# Insert a blank page in Adobe Livecycle

Tags: adobe, pdf-generation, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I have template from which I generate lot of PDF files through XML input. The page count should always be even. I want to insert a blank page dynamically when odd pages are detected. Can you help with the scripting to insert blank page?

Answer (score 0):

Can your template have a blank page that is hidden, then upon completion do something like this?

```
if (xfa.layout.pageSpan(form1)%2 == 1 && blankPage.presence == "hidden") 
    blankPage.presence = "visible";
else if (xfa.layout.pageSpan(form1)%2 == 1) blankPage.presence = "hidden";
```

That should pick up whether it's odd or not and add the page.

"form1" is the name of your form, of course, and "blankPage" is the empty page that you hide when you design the form.